# Developing a simple voice driven web app using web speech API

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-api

I am new to web development and I am trying to develop a simple voice driven web application using Web Speech API.
I used [this](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API) simple tutorial to learn the basics of a voice driven application.

Here is the code that I wrote as a simple start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>        
       var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
       recognition.continuous = true;
       recognition.onresult = function(event) {
           alert("onresult even handler");
       }
       function startButton(event) {
          recognition.start();
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "text">
      <button id="start_button" onclick="startButton(event)">
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I open my html page in google chrome browser and click on start this is what I see:

[image]

**And when I click on the crossed camera icon I see the following drop down:**

[image]

Even when I choose "Ask if file -- wants to access your camera and microphone" option and reload the page the same thing repeats itself.

When I did more research on this I came to know that google chrome allows only a secure site (i.e https://) to access your camera and microphone. If its not https then chrome blocks it without asking the user. But I am unable to understand why my local file is being blocked from using the microphone. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy the HTML project on the server. You can do that by deploying it on any localhost server.

Media related HTML files do  not work properly unless deployed on a server.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSpeechAPI only works for files treated via https:// or http:// NOT file:///

You need a webserver to which you have access to/where you store the files on.

When you have no webserver available you can use google sky as webserver/for hosting your index.html (name MUST be index.html) and all javascript and css stuff:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html

Answer (score -1):

I may have a solution for you:

**1.** Go into google chrome settings
**2.** Click advanced settings
**3.** Click show advanced settings.
**4.** Under "privacy" click content settings
**5.** Go to the media section (near the bottom) and click "Allow all sites to use a plugin on my computer"

Really hope this helps!

If you extra help, check out this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj7bTQhOD_4) for more information.

Comment: Under media section in the privacy content settings there are only 2 options. 1) Ask me when a site requires access to my camera and microphone 2) Do not allow sites to access my camera and microphone. And I have the first option selected. Also when I click on manage exceptions chrome does not allow me to add hostnames to the exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not allow" are you getting an error of some sort?

Comment: No. When I click on manage exceptions under cookies or javascript etc I get an editable field under hostname where I can enter a URL. But when I click manage exceptions under media I dont get a editable field under the hostname. Hence it does not allow me to add an exception.